# How to build HQL query, thats joins subtables marked LAZY, automatically?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql, left-join

I have some entity:

```
  public class Album extends GenericAuditedEntity {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> itemSet = new HashSet<Item>();
  }
```

And when i run HQL like this:
em.createQuery("select a from Album a").getResults()

it produses many SQL queries:
One for select data from Album's table. Smth like this: select .... from Album_table;
And one query for each fetched row, for selecting items. Smth like this: 
select .... from Item_table iwhere i.Album_id = :Album_id;

But when i run em.createQuery("
select a.id, b.id 
from Album a 
left join Item i
").getResults()

it produses one SQL query. But it's result is list of some parameters, that i need put into the entities manually.

How can i build HQL with joins automatically and automatically put the results to the entities? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [join fetch](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins):

```
em.createQuery("select a.id, b.id from Album a left join fetch Item i ").getResults();
```

Note that there are certain side effects to that, described in detail the above link.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `join fetch` then you don't need the IDs, you can retrieve the Entity as Hibernate will also populate the association in it's first-level cache

```
em.createQuery("select a from Album a left join fetch a.itemSet").getResultList();
```

However if you are retrieving the IDs but want populated Objects/Entities then consider using a Constructor

```
em.createQuery("select new com.xxx.AlbumItem(a.id, b.id) from Album a left join fetch a.itemSet b").getResultList();
```

Comment: Sorry. But I'd wrote about only IDs for example. In real i need to fetch more than 100 fieds and join about 10 entities, for example.

Answer (score -1):

dont use lazy fetching. set fetch type to eager

Comment: That's generally a bad advice. It may be useful from time to time, but setting all associations to eager fetch may result in you pulling the entire database over on each `get()`

Comment: Yes. We have big and old project. With big entities. Eager anywhere - is very slow.